# C# specific visibility for some methods

Tags: c#, visibility

I have two classes in a namespace and these classes need to call each other like this:

```
public class A
{
    void MethodVisibleToB() {}
}
public class B
{
    void MethodVisibleToA() {}
}
```

I want the methods to not be seen neither from inside the dll nor from outside. I wanted only class A to see `B.MethodVisibleToA` and only class B to see `A.MethodVisibleToA`.

I usually restrain visibility of a method with nested classes, but this time it is not possible as well as unnecessarily complex. Can you suggest a way to prevent this methods to be called from outside?

The options I have now are not that good:

- make all public (meh),
- make all internal and move A and B in another dll (not doable)

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that the classes are in the same namespace in the same assembly

**Solution**: I took Mrinal Kamboj's suggestion and implemented the interfaces explicitly:

```
internal interface IA
{
    void VisibleByB();
}

internal interface IB
{
    void VisibleByA();
}

public class A : IA
{
    void IA.VisibleByB() { }
}

public class B : IB
{
    void IB.VisibleByA() { }
}
```

**Event more pervert solution to a pervert problem**: this will prevent the two interfaces and relative methods to be accessed from other classes and even subclasses:

```
public static class ClassAreNotMeantToBeUsedThisWay
{
    interface IA
    {
        void VisibleByB();
    }

    interface IB
    {
        void VisibleByA();
    }

    public class A : IA
    {
        void IA.VisibleByB() { }
    }

    public class B : IB
    {
        void IB.VisibleByA() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Use an interface for both A and B and explicitly implement the methods and access it

Comment: The question was not that clear, I wanted the methods to not be seen neither from inside the dll nor from outside. I wanted only class A to see B.MethodVisibleToA and only class B to see A.MethodVisibleToA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an Interface and implement Explicitly as follows:

```
interface InterfaceA
{
    void MethodVisibleToB();
}

interface InterfaceB
{
    void MethodVisibleToA();
}

public class A : InterfaceA
{
    void InterfaceA.MethodVisibleToB() { }
}
public class B : InterfaceB
{
    void InterfaceB.MethodVisibleToA() { }
}
```

**Access as follows:**

```
InterfaceA a = new A();
a.MethodVisibleToB();

InterfaceB b = new B();
b.MethodVisibleToA();
```

this way method would be available when wrapped up in an interface type, will not be available when not wrapped in an `Interface type`, but a class type

Comment: Welcome, though by standard use case such interface methods shall only be designed to create strict access restrictions, when you want end user to know what are we trying to achieve. Like Serialize in some classes implementing ISerializable

Answer (score 2):

You can mark the methods as [`internal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal)

> Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly

See the following example:

```
public class A
{
    internal void MethodVisibleToB() {}
}

public class B
{
    A aInstance = new A();

    internal void MethodVisibleToA() 
    {
        aInstance.MethodVisibleToB(); // this can only be called by methods that are within the same assembly as B
    }
}
```

#### Addendum

If you need to access the method from the outside, you can use [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) in the assembly where `A` and `B` are located. Anyway, I'd recommend this for a very restricted scope only, e.g. (unit-)tests. Place this line in any `.cs` file in your assembly (without an namespace)

```
[assembly: System.InternalsVisibleTo("MyAssembly.Tests")]
```

Comment: The question was not that clear, I wanted the methods to not be seen neither from inside the dll nor from outside. I wanted only class A to see `B.MethodVisibleToA` and only class B to see `A.MethodVisibleToA`